# Unable to copy another model's attributes correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following associations and then action in my Observer:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price, :name, :watch_price
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :store
  has_many :product_subscriptions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :product_subscribers, :through => :product_subscriptions, :class_name => 'User'
end

class ProductSubscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :product_subscriber, :class_name => 'User'
  attr_accessible :watched_price, :watched_name
end

class ProductObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
 def after_create(product)
   ProductSubscription.new(product.attributes.merge({
       :watched_name => name,  
       :watched_price => price, 
       :store_id => :store_id,
      }))
  end
end
```

The code above, successfully creates the `ProductSubscription` with the `user_id` and `product_id` but `:watched_name` and `:watched_price` aren't filled with the original `Product` `:price` and `:name`.

I noticed the issue lies in this. Which doesn't make any sense because when I look in the database, it is assigned as I mentioned above:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: product_id
```

Now I do have other fields that are apart of the `Product` model that aren't apart of the `ProductSubscription` model so maybe its screwing up because of that?

I don't want the `product_id` to be mass assignable. How could I correct this?

Comment: Why does a ProductSubscription have duplicates of the Product's attributes in the first place?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I'm using the ProductSubscription to "watch" for lower prices by first copying the Product's attributes and then comparing the copied attributes to other similar Product's.

Answer (score 2):

Your hash values must reference the attribute methods, not some symbols. That way, the method returning the respective attribute value gets called and the value gets inserted into the hash. The symbols you used have no meaning whatsoever.

```
ProductSubscription.new(product.attributes.merge({
    :watched_name => name,
    :watched_price => price, 
    :store_id => store_id,
  }))
end
```

Also, you don't seem to save your new `ProductSubscription`. Just calling `new` won't persist the object to the database. Use something like `create` instead.

And finally, as Andrew Marshall said, your database design is not really optimal. Copying whole table rows around is not going to offer great performance. Instead you will soon suffer from inconsistencies and the hassles of keeping all the copied data up-to-date. You really should learn about joins and the concepts of [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org./wiki/Database_normalization)